# print time intervals between start time and end time using php

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I have to print the time intervals between to times using php.

I have an inputs like

```
$start_time = "09:45:00";
$end_time = "2:45:00";
$interval = "+60 minutes";

im printing array like 

$tarray = ['09:45:00', '10:45:00', '11:45:00', '12:45:00', '1:45:00', '2:45:00'];
```

But i want to print array like

```
$result = ['09:45:00-10:45:00', '10:45:00-11:45:00', '11:45:00-12:45:00', '12:45:00-1:45:00', '1:45:00'-'2:45:00'];
```

And from  result array i have to separate am and pm times also.

```
$am_times = ['09:45:00-10:45:00', '10:45:00-11:45:00', '11:45:00-12:45:00'];
$pm_times = ['12:45:00-1:45:00', '1:45:00'-'2:45:00'];
```

I have tried like below

```
  Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
[items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 121
                [showroom_id] => 22
                [showroom_open_day] => Monday
                [showroom_start_time] => 01:15:00
                [showroom_end_time] => 03:15:00
                [created_at] => 2017-07-03 10:43:36
                [updated_at] => 2017-07-03 10:43:36
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 122
                [showroom_id] => 22
                [showroom_open_day] => Tuesday
                [showroom_start_time] => 02:15:00
                [showroom_end_time] => 22:00:00
                [created_at] => 2017-07-03 10:43:36
                [updated_at] => 2017-07-03 10:43:36
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 123
                [showroom_id] => 22
                [showroom_open_day] => Wednesday
                [showroom_start_time] => 02:00:00
                [showroom_end_time] => 09:00:00
                [created_at] => 2017-07-03 10:43:36
                [updated_at] => 2017-07-03 10:43:36
            )

    )

)

  foreach ($showroom_timings_result as $st) 
    {            
       $start          = $st->showroom_start_time;
       $end            = $st->showroom_end_time;
       $interval       = '+60 minutes';
       $times_array[$st->showroom_open_day] = getTimeSlots($start, $end, $interval);
    }

  function getTimeSlots($start='00:00:00', $end='23:45:00', $interval='+60 minutes') {
    $start_str      = strtotime($start);
    $end_str        = strtotime($end);
    $now_str        = $start_str;

    $data = [];

    while($now_str <= $end_str){
        $data[]     = date('H:i:s', $now_str);
        $now_str    = strtotime($interval, $now_str);
    }

    return $data;
 }
```

Please help me out, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what value `$showroom_timings_result` have? can you show us the output of `echo "<pre/>";print_r($showroom_timings_result);`

Comment: I updated mu question, showroom_timings_result iam getting like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function

```
function getTimeSlots($start = '00:00:00', $end = '23:45:00', $interval = '+15 minutes')
{
    $start_str = strtotime($start);
    $end_str = strtotime($end);
    $now_str = $start_str;
    $midTime = strtotime('12:00:00');

    $data = [];
    $preTime = '';
    $index = '';

    while ($now_str <= $end_str) {
        if ($now_str <= $midTime)
            $index = 'AM';
        else
            $index = 'PM';
        if ($preTime) {
            $data[$index][] = $preTime . '-' . date('H:i:s', $now_str);
        }
        $preTime = date('H:i:s', $now_str);
        $now_str = strtotime($interval, $now_str);
    }

    return $data;
}
```

It produce out put as

[image]

I thing it will work for you.

Comment: If i want to skip the time interval for lunch (1 hour) what shoul i have to do?

Comment: you can pass the interval time to function and check the time in the while loop like `$now_str == $interval` then do nothing else run the as usual code.

Comment: means in first while loop only?

Comment: when **time interval for lunch (1 hour) ** time will be is it static or dynamic ?

Comment: static value only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148310/discussion-between-bibhudatta-sahoo-and-user3668438).